# UITextVIew is not moving up while typing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, iqkeyboardmanager

I installed a pod file `IQKeyboardManager` in my project, but it is not working.

Here is screenshot,
[image]

**Image 1**: This is my one of view for creating a ticket.

Subject and Message are text view, not text field.

When I start typing in Subject (subjectTextView) then I am not able to see what I'm typing & the same thing is happening in the message (messageTextView). I am not able to see content what I am typing in textview (see Image 2 A)

When I click on done then we can able see content (see image 2 B)

is there any solution?
When I start typing in subjectTextView and messageTextview I want to move textview up while typing.

Update : 
I added following code in appdelegate file, still not working

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have to enable manager from appdelegate

Comment: @dahiya_boy  [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnableAutoToolbar:true];   this line I have to write in appdelegate, right ?

Comment: Write this -> `[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];`

Comment: I added this line still it is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add below code in App Delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method,'

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
```

or You can add in viewWillDisappear or viewDidLoad method in that class.

You may be done one small mistake.
Have you written anything in viewWillAppear or viewWillDisappear method?

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable `IQKeyboardManager`. You can enable it in app delegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

**Swift 4 Xcode 9**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
    return true
}
```

**Objective C**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I added, this line in appdelegate file, still not working

Comment: kindly take text field, basically you take textView

Answer (score 2):

You need enable the `IQKeyboardManager` in your `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method using

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];

    return YES;
}
```

should work

Answer (score 0):

try by adding below line in your Create Ticket Controller's **viewWillAppear** to re-enable

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] setEnable:YES];
```